# Javascript Confirm box redirection in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my code

```
 Type cstype = this.GetType();
            ClientScriptManager cs = this.ClientScript;
            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "Script"))
            {
               String csScriptText = "confirm('Are you sure you want to leave the page');document.location='Default.aspx'";
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "TestScript", csScriptText, true);

            }
```

I m trying to implement the  confirmbox in my web application which comes up when user hits signout button ...with the options ok and cancel with the above code.with the above code i am able to redirect to the default page when user hits "ok" on the confirmbox.I want to remain on the same page when user hits the "cancel" button on the confirmbox .How do i do it ?

Answer (score 3):

The confirm function returns a `boolean` value indicating whether the user **selected OK** or **Cancel**. So all you need to do is to **redirect only** if this function returns true:

```
String csScriptText = "if (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave the page')){document.location='Default.aspx';}";
```

Comment: I did try adding the conditional but still either you hit "ok" or "cancel" its redirecting to the default page.I want to remain in the same page when "cancel" of the confirm box is hit and redirect to the default page when "ok" is hit

Answer (score 0):

Just add a conditional to the redirect.

```
Type cstype = this.GetType();
            ClientScriptManager cs = this.ClientScript;
            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "Script"))
            {
               String csScriptText = "if(confirm('Are you sure you want to leave the page')) {document.location='Default.aspx'}";
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "TestScript", csScriptText, true);

            }
```

Comment: I did try adding the conditional but still either you hit "ok" or "cancel" its redirecting to the default page.I want to remain in the same page when "cancel" of the confirm box is hit and redirect to the default page when "ok" is hit

Answer (score 0):

```
if (confirm('some text here')) {
    window.location = "Default.aspx";
}
```